# Self-made UTP cable not working

Tags: networking, lan, cable

I'm trying to create my own UTP cables. It's fun and cheaper than buying single cables instead.
Now I struggling to make my cables work. The cables will be used to connect a PC to simple a unmanaged Netgear switch. I tested all the ports on the switches I have and they all work.

These are the specs:

- All cables are around 1 meter long.
- RJ45 Connector
- Printing on the cable itself says: UTP CAT5e
- I use the following color schema:

Pin #1 is on the left side ([see this example](https://www.sbprojects.net/knowledge/concab/utp/orientation.png)). I use straight-through so I use the same methods on both ends.

- Pin #1: Orange/White
- Pin #2: Orange
- Pin #3: Green/White
- Pin #4: Blue
- Pin #5: Blue/White
- Pin #6: Green
- Pin #7: Brown/White
- Pin #8: Brown
- Ground (I don't have ground)

I have a LAN-cable tester set, I tested all my cables, and all the lights for pin 1-8 light up in the correct order. I made 3 cables this way. When I connect the cables to the device and switch, no LEDS whatsoever starts blinking. I think I doing something fundamentally wrong.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What devices are you trying to connect? If the LAN-cable tester say they are correct, then they are correct. Unless you made them straight through but you needed crossover cables.

Comment: Can you show photos of your actual connectors on the cables? What's good enough for a basic "light the LED up" test might not be good enough for high-frequency data signals.

Comment: @eventHandler PC to switch (unmanaged Netgear) 8 ports

Comment: Can you provide more details of the exact bulk cable product and 8P8C male connector products you're using? One thing I'm looking for: Most 8P8C male connectors are designed for stranded conductor cables, and don't make good contact with solid-core cables. So it would be nice to verify both.